# Javascript global variable is not getting inside the function

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following javascript code in my page.

```
var data = {items: []};
var item_flag=false;
var check_flag=false;
var count = 0;
function add(){
    if(check_flag){
        //block A
    }else{
        data.items.push(
           {item: item, quantity: quantity, price: price}
        );
    }
}
```

Here I have declared the variable data as globally.In function add() I am trying to push values to the global variable data in the else condition.
but I am getting error, Type error:data is undefined
Inside the if condition the variable data is accessible.

Please help me to find a solution
Thanks.

Comment: I suspect you're calling `add()` from a function defined prior to the variable declaration. Please show us where you call `add()`.

Comment: And your check_flag is false so it shouldnt get there. And all the vars you try to add are nowhere to be found.

Comment: Without the rest of the code it's difficult to work out what's going on. If we know where `add()` is called we may have more of a chance of fixing it. Also, `item`, `quantity` and `price` in the above code will also be `undefined`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
function data() { this.items = []; }  

function items(item, quantity, price){   
   this.item= item;     
   this.quantity= quantity;    
   this.price= price;   
}

var Datas = new data();   //Global variable
function add(item, quantity, price){
    if(check_flag){
         //block A
    } else {
         Datas.items[Datas.items.length] = new items(item, quantity, price);
    }
}
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/70joxtg1/)

Comment: Down voter, please explain, which part of the code is not working?